# Same password results in different AES keys in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am attempting to implement a basic example of AES encryption across two devices in Java. However using the same password(128 bit) on both devices to generate an AES key results in different keys on both devices, each time we run the application. So we are unable to decrypt the text that we send between devices.

The methods I'm using are below, they are slightly modified versions of code I've found elsewhere:

```
public String encryptMessage(String message, String password) throws Exception {

    // Creating key and cipher
    SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");


    byte[] iv = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    //AES cipher
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

    // encrypt the text
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, ivspec);

    byte[] encrypted;

    encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());

    return new String(encrypted, "UTF-8");
}

public String decryptMessage(String encryptedMessage, String password) throws Exception {

    // Creating key and cipher
    byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");

    SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(passwordBytes, "AES");

    byte[] iv = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    //AES cipher
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

    // decrypting the text
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey, ivspec);
    String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedMessage.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));

    //returning decrypted text
    return decrypted;
}
```

Every time I run this code and print out aesKey, it is different.

My understanding of AES and symmetric encryption is that given the same password it should generate the same key, otherwise how is it able to decrypt the artefact?
Have I got the wrong end of the stick wrt AES or can someone suggest what might be going on?

Comment: You can also just hash the password and add salt to it. That's enough to secure your password.

Comment: When using a password for encryption is is necessary to derive the encryption key with a slow method and random salt. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead use a key derivation function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions with a CPU utilization of ~100ms. The random salt must be provided for decryption. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct and the key in your code is the same.

You can't "print" the `aesKey` since `SecretKeySpec` has no `toString()` method. So the built-in `Object.toString()` will be called, which just prints the *address of the object in memory*

```
javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@14c7f    // <--- useless info //
```

There are just a few issues with your code:

- Don't convert encrypted bytes to a UTF-8 string. There can be combinations which are invalid in UTF-8, as well as 00 bytes. Use Base64 or Hex encoding for printing encrypted data.
- You shouldn't use ASCII bytes as a key, that greatly reduces security of the key. *Derive* a key from the password, at least with SHA-256, but preferably PBKDF2 or scrypt.
- Use a high entropy random IV and store it with the ciphertext.

Here's an updated version demonstrating that it's working:

```
public static String encryptMessageGH(String message, String password) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] key = sha.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    byte[] encrypted = new byte[iv.length + ciphertext.length];
    System.arraycopy(iv, 0, encrypted, 0, iv.length);
    System.arraycopy(ciphertext, 0, encrypted, iv.length, ciphertext.length);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
}

public static String decryptMessageGH(String encryptedMessage, String password) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] key = sha.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    byte[] encrypted = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedMessage);
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, iv, 0, iv.length);
    byte[] ciphertext = new byte[encrypted.length - iv.length];
    System.arraycopy(encrypted, iv.length, ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(ciphertext), "UTF-8");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String orig = "Test message";
    String enc = encryptMessageGH(orig, "abcdef123");
    System.out.println("Encrypted: " + enc);
    String dec = decryptMessageGH(enc, "abcdef123");
    System.out.println("Decrypted: " + dec);
}
```

Output:

```
Encrypted: lcqcd9UZpjLSY9SsQ/N7kV/cpdzL3c7HQcCSiIs6p/k=
Decrypted: Test message
```

Comment: Deriving a key from the password with SHA-256 is not secure, use a key derivation function as in the answer. The key derivation salt will also need to be provided, it can be part of the final message I the same manner as the IV.

Comment: I fully agree. Those should be the next improvements that OP can implement.

Comment: As a proof of concept it is now working. Thanks for your help!